# Pandas DataFrame constructor with Series

Tags: pandas

```
df5=pd.DataFrame(pd.Series([1,2,3]), index=['a','b','c'])

0
a   NaN
b   NaN
c   NaN
```

Why values are **NAN** rather than (1,2,3)?

Answer (score 1):

Because default index values of `Series` are `0,1,2`, what is different like index values of `DataFrame`, so output are missing values:

```
print (pd.Series([1,2,3]))
0    1
1    2
2    3
dtype: int64
```

Possible solution is same `index` values:

```
df5=pd.DataFrame(pd.Series([1,2,3], index=['a','b','c']), index=['a','b','c'])
```

Or converting values to numpy array:

```
df5=pd.DataFrame(pd.Series([1,2,3]).to_numpy(), index=['a','b','c'])
```

---

If need `DataFrame`:

```
df5 = pd.Series([1,2,3], index=['a','b','c']).to_frame()
```

Answer (score 1):

Because paranthesis should be closed after `index=` :
**df5=pd.DataFrame(pd.Series([1,2,3], index=['a','b','c']))**

Answer (score 1):

Because the Series itself has to have an index.

So you have two alternatives:

1. Build de DataFrame with an Indexed Series:

`df5 = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series([1,2,3],index=['a','b','c']))`

2. Build the DataFrame with a list and specify for that the index:

`df5 = pd.DataFrame(([1,2,3]),index=['a','b','c']))`